# Login script wrong password fault

Tags: php, html

My login script has just all of a sudden stopped working.
I keep getting the "Wrong Username or Password" message.

Here is my login page:

```
<form method="post" action="http://myurl.net/checklogin.php"><div style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">  

<h2 style="margin-top: 25px;">Enter your username and password to login:</h2>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto; text-align: left;">
              <tr>                <td style="text-align: right;" valign="middle">Username:</td>
                <td><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;" valign="middle">Password:</td>
                <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
              </tr>
 <tr style="text-align: center;" valign="middle">
                <td colspan="2"><div class="actionMsg">Please change your password after you login.</div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="text-align: center;" valign="middle">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Log in" onClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Logging In...'; this.form.submit();">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="text-align: center;" valign="middle">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="about.html">Having trouble logging in?</a> | <a href="404.html">Forgot your password?</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></div></form>
```

Then here is checklogin.php

```
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost", "edited this out", "");
mysql_select_db("");

$tbl_name="users"; 

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Replace counting function based on database you are using.
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if ($count == 1) {
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  echo"Wow were back up";
} else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

echo "The login script is down while its being worked on. Come back later";
```

I have checked in the DB and the username and password I'm using are right.... and the column names are right as well.

**The problem is fixed i added

```
session_start();
```

to the html form thanks to everyone that helped**

Comment: I really really really really hope this isn't code from a live site. Please look up best practices for working with passwords on the web.

Comment: i forgot to put session start on the html login page all works fine now

Comment: @user1121083 Plain text passwords... really?

Comment: coz ov these codes websites go down!!!!

Comment: I know the only bad part are plain text password

Comment: i added session_start(); onto the html form which got it to work

Comment: @user1121083 You should definitely rethink your website security. If you have time, try to do a scan over your website with a vulnerability scanner. That will give you an idea of what me and the people commenting above are talking about.

Comment: Note to self: Check src of all websites you are about to create an account on and if the form action is checklogin.php and user/pass inputs are "myusername" and "mypassword"...do not register.